# Xen API Ruby Bindings?

Tags: ruby, xen

Does anyone know if there is a full XenServer API implementation in ruby floating around out there?  I found this: http://github.com/rubiojr/pangea/tree/master  but its read only and not fully built out.

Answer (score 1):

Libvirt is an abstraction layer that can work with different kinds of VMs, like xen, kvm, virtualbox, ...

http://libvirt.org/

It has ruby bindings

http://libvirt.org/ruby/

I also found using libvirt itself to be an enormous gain.

Answer (score 0):

You can find unofficial ruby bindings for XenAPI [here](https://github.com/meineerde/xenapi.rb).

N.B: It only supports http/network based sessions only. Support for unix sockets is not included, which shouldn't be an issue as ruby isn't part of the XenServer distribution.